# Kivy - Why doesn't image source update?

Tags: python, image, kivy

I want to update the source of an image when `root.stop_recording()` is called in the kv file, but the command `self.ids.Mic_Image.source = self.Mic_Loading` doesn't update the image. Instead the previous image (a gif opened in a zip file) just freezes. How can I fix this?

Here's the relevant section of my Python code:

```
class IdentifyItem(Screen):
    Mic_Loading = StringProperty()
    Mic_Listening = StringProperty()
    Mic_Pressed = StringProperty()
    Mic_Static = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(IdentifyItem, self).__init__()
        self.Mic_Loading = 'Mic_Loading.zip'
        self.Mic_Listening = "Mic_Listening.zip"
        self.audio_to_text = AudioToText()

    def on_press(self):
        self.ids.Mic_Image.anim_loop = 0
        self.ids.Mic_Image.source = self.Mic_Listening
        self.record = self.audio_to_text.start()
        self.audio_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.record, args=(),
                                             daemon=True)  # initialises an instance of Thread. 
        self.audio_thread.start()  # starts the Thread instance
        
    def stop_recording(self):
        self.ids.Mic_Image.source = self.Mic_Loading
        self.audio_to_text.stop()
```

And the .kv file:

```
        Image:
            id: Mic_Image
            source: "Mic_Static.png"
            opacity: 1
            anim_delay: 0
            size_hint: (0.9,0.9)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y": 0.2}

        Button:
            id: mic
            background_color: (1, 1, 1, 0)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "y":0.08}
            size_hint: (0.26,0.19)
            on_press:
                root.on_press()
            on_release:
                root.stop_recording()
```